# DHCP and connection problems on cascade switches and routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I have the following configuration (one switch at a building floor):

[image]

The workstations are all DHCP enabled to get IP automatically. When I power up everything works fine. After some time (2 hs) I loose my internet connection though WIFI2. Even rebooting this router it does not return.
After some more time it seens that the DHCP service on 192.168.0.1 is lost on the whole network, as when I reboot a workstation it can´t get the IP address on the 192.168.0.X range (it gets something like 162.*.*.*).

After that happens I do power off the routers and switches in the following order: 
1. power on the main router
2. power on the switches
3. power on the second wifi router

After that it runs fine, until the WiFI2 fails again and the cycle restarts...

Anys idea of what is going wrong with this configuration ?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help...

Comment: BTW: The image upload to superuser is not working... I had to place it somewhere else...

Comment: More personal opinion than hard fact, but I don't like those DIR-615s. The best they seem good for is as pure wifi APs with all their 'smart' switched off. They're also only 100BaseT. If the 3Com is capable of doing the same job, I'd swap them over.

Comment: This are somehow old equipment... I can´t change them for now... I just wanna know what´s going wrong with my configuration...